# Issue with angular2 ng generate command

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am running this command

```
ng generate component app/body-top/create-index
```

and getting this output:

```
installing component
    Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
        at Object.getAppFromConfig (/Volumes/disk2/programs/nodejs/easyes/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/app-utils.js:6:19)
        at Class.normalizeEntityName (/Volumes/disk2/programs/nodejs/easyes/node_modules/@angular/cli/blueprints/component/index.js:106:39)
        at Class.Blueprint._normalizeEntityName (/Volumes/disk2/programs/nodejs/easyes/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/blueprint.js:454:24)
        at Class.Blueprint.install (/Volumes/disk2/programs/nodejs/easyes/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/blueprint.js:513:8)
        at Class.run (/Volumes/disk2/programs/nodejs/easyes/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/tasks/generate-from-blueprint.js:59:49)
        at Class.run (/Volumes/disk2/programs/nodejs/easyes/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/commands/generate.js:71:17)
        at Class.<anonymous> (/Volumes/disk2/programs/nodejs/easyes/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:134:17)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

I tried so many things to fix the issue but no luck.

Version Details :

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 7.7.2
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.8
@angular/compiler: 2.4.8
@angular/core: 2.4.8
@angular/forms: 2.4.8
@angular/http: 2.4.8
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.8
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.8
@angular/router: 3.4.8
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
```

Comment: Created project with fountainjs and have exactly same error with these versions:  @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.4
node: 7.7.3
os: linux x64
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.4

Comment: If you open `app-utils.js:6:19`, you see the problem is cli can not find the app. I just created a new project with cli (not with fountainjs) and there is no problem.